# Two animations with 1 second delay inbetween

Tags: java, android

I want to built a splashscreen for android, where the logo is animated two times:

- Fly from left to center
- After 1 sec, fly from center to right

The first thing works well:

```
Animation animLeft2Center = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_left_to_center);
mLogo.startAnimation(animLeft2Center);
```

But I don't get the second animation to work.

```
Animation animCenter2Right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_center_to_right);
mLogo.startAnimation(animCenter2Right);
```

How can I set a delay of 1 second between both and then start the second animation?

I couldn't find something like `setStartDelay` and also it does not fire both animations after each other.

Comment: Did you tried to use [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) with first animation and let second one start once first one is completed (`onAnimationEnd`)? If you want to just use one animation you can even proceed by defining an animation set at XML level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do it in this way:

```
Animation animLeft2Center = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_left_to_center);

mLogo.startAnimation(animLeft2Center);  
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 1 second
      Animation animCenter2Right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_center_to_right);
      mLogo.startAnimation(animCenter2Right);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you! What about the "this" in the loadAnimation?

Comment: Could you give me a short example? I'm very new to android. Would be awesome!

Comment: Try with YourActivityName.this

Comment: You, Sir are a hero!